# Maven setup for spark project in Eclipse Scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven

Im using Eclipse for Scala IDE to develop a Spark application. 
Im using a Maven project, but when i try to **import sparkcon** like :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
```

I have the error :

> object apache is not a member of package org can you help me to setup
>   spark dependancies

Comment: Have you compile your meven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the Spark dependency in your pom.xml file. As of now, the latest version of Spark can be obtained by putting:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

in the dependencies in your pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the tutorial from

https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/04/02/setting-up-a-spark-project-with-maven.html

Online tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4sO-VgqHLp4